# Having issues trying to save file as SVG in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, icon, svg

Created my first icon and now trying to save it as .SVG, but not going as planned. When I view my icon in Inkscape it shows that it is missing some objects, or the object in question is distorted. I have two screenshots of each version here below:

Here is what the icon should look like-
[image: Icon in Illustrator]

and here's how it looks in Inkscape-
[image: how Inkscape is viewing the icon]

Comment: Can you make an [edit] to include the SVG code?

Comment: The area you're having issues with, is it locked?

Answer (score 2):

Your issue could be a likelihood of possibilities.  I would imagine that area is a clipping and/or a masked object.  If that is a clipping or masked area that would your issue.  When creating SVGs the object in question should be clean of obscurities.  Have you looked at your SVG in an outline view?  That would help diagnose what is going on.  I would also open your SVG in a text editor so you can identify what layer and location the issue is coming from if it is actually an object.  If you can make an edit to your question with the actual SVG we can take a look and possibly assist further.

Try cleaning the area in question with building correct shapes and their own layer and using the Pathfinder tool.  Cycle back and forth with the outline view in Illustrator.  [Some questions on pathfinder](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-illustrator+pathfinder).